# Cant find .gz file in AIX

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, aix

I basically have written a shell script in AIX that will delete some old log file and will compress some .

This is my script

```
#!/bin/sh
###
### Static variables
###
nmon_dir="/var/log/applog/nmon"
cd $nmon_dir
find $nmon_dir -xdev -type f -mtime +360 -name "*.nmon*" -exec rm {} \;
find $nmon_dir -xdev -type f -mtime +300 -name "*.nmon" -exec gzip {} \;
```

I could delete the files as i wanted but that I am not sure whether it compressed those file . Because i couldn't find `.gz` file both in `root` or  `/var/log/applog/nmon` path .

Need Help!

Comment: What happens if you execute those commands on the commandline?

Comment: If you first delete, no compression can be done

Comment: Its same . Doesn't throw any error couldn't find .gz either .

Comment: Of course it is not the same. Try this: `rm file; cat file`  and then `cat file; rm file`.

Comment: Look at first it will retain 360 day's log file and delete remaining , later it will retain 300 day's and compress rest !!!

Comment: @jm666 Those files exists !!!

Comment: sry - my BAD. I missed the difference in +360 +300. Excuse ;)

Comment: @jm666 Please read the question before you comment something like that:)

Comment: OK now I see you have 300 in one line and 360 in the other one. My fault!

Comment: @fedorqui Yes it is !

Comment: By the way, as I commented in the other question you posted regarding this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/q/16833343/1983854), you'd better use logrotate not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes that seems like nice tool . But i need authorization to do so . For now i have run this script successfully .

Comment: @DeepeshShetty How did you resolve this?  You might want to supply your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like your KSH might be taking the `{}` you pass to find as a compound command definition instead of as the filename placeholder. Try escaping it, I use it as `\{\}` and it never gives me problems.